# RewriteRules and ErrorDocument rules not working for SSL vhosts

Tags: apache, url-rewriting, virtualhost, httpd.conf, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

Known 404 requests are not being redirected for https... and only display a generic `Not Found` 404 ... http requests on port 80 are begin rewritten just fine...

**Notes:** Using http.conf files (not .htaccess) on a Apache Server (2.4.39) spun up through `AWS elastic beanstalk` on 64bit `Amazon Linux`/2.8.9.

Example:

- example.com/fake
- sub.example.com/fake

> **Not Found**
>
> The requested URL /fake was not found on this server.

.

### My config file has 2 parts...

**Part 1** redirects http to https... this RewriteRule works perfectly...

```
  <VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName sub.example.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/sub
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto} !https
    RewriteRule . https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R]
  </VirtualHost>
```

**Part 2** is supposed to rewrite sub.example.com/fake to sub.subdomain.com/?url=$1

```
  <VirtualHost *:443>
    ServerName sub.example.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/sub
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?url=$1 [L]
  </VirtualHost>
```

I thought the rewrite rule was the part that is miss-written, but it's not because even the following attempts did not work.

```
  <VirtualHost *:443>
    ServerName sub.example.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/sub
    ErrorDocument 404 "No go bro..."
  </VirtualHost>
```

I thought is was only an issue with sub domains but this didn't work either.

```
  <VirtualHost *:443>
    ServerName example.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/www
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://google.com [L]
    ErrorDocument 404 "No go bro 1..."
  </VirtualHost>

  <VirtualHost *:443>
    ServerName sub.example.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/sub
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://google.com [L]
    ErrorDocument 404 "No go bro 2..."
  </VirtualHost>
```

Tried adding overrides as suggested, but that didn't work

```
  <VirtualHost *:443>
    <Directory /var/www/html/www>
      AllowOverride All
      Allow From All
    </Directory>
    ServerName ecample.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/www
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://google.com [L]
    ErrorDocument 404 "No go bro..."
  </VirtualHost>
```

[One reference](http://tltech.com/info/rewriterule-in-htaccess-vs-httpd-conf/) said the RewriteRules needed to be in Directory tags within the VirtualHost tags... so I tried that with no luck

```
  <VirtualHost *:443>
    ServerName example.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/www
    <Directory /var/www/html/www>
      Allow From All
      AllowOverride All
      RewriteEngine On
      RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f [OR]
      RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
      RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?url=$1 [L]
      ErrorDocument 404 "No go bro..."
    </Directory>
  </VirtualHost>
```

The DocumentRoot paths are correct as all known urls `example.com` & `sub.example.com` work fine just 404 is where there is a problem.

Comment: Do you have the `Multiviews` option on? turn it off if that's the case, because the rest looks completely fine to me.

Comment: Not sure how to do that. Can you elaborate. Would I put "Options -MultiViews" in each VirtualHost block?

Comment: I would do it on a server level, unless you have a use for it on any other virtualhost. That option is the most unless and confusing one when working with server side scripting and rewrite rules.

Comment: Did not have the option on. Even added `Options -MultiViews` with no luck.

Comment: what happens if you replace `RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?url=$1 [L]` with `RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://google.com [L]` ? It seems like it doesn't rewrite anything on the SSL vhost.

Comment: Just tried with Google.com and shows "Not Found" ...

Comment: The funny thing is is works in the other vhost... Seems stupid to ask, but are you editing the correct vhost?

Comment: Yeah... I even added it to all vhosts just to see if any of them would perform a rewrite (or simple 404 text) none of them are working. Even the main example.com not just sub domains...

Comment: I suggest defining separate logs per vhost for debugging, using the rewrite:trace8 logging, showing apachectl -S, and using a command-line client to troubleshoot.

Comment: Just to make sure: Do you have at least both `SSLCertificateFile` and `SSLCertificateKeyFile` directives with proper certificates in every `<VirtualHost *:443>`?

Comment: @digijay - using AWS certificate manager for SSL and installing in via Elastic beanstalk. It is installed correctly, because all the known URLs are working just fine. http redirects to https and sub domains like sub.example.com work just fine. It's only a problem when it comes to a 404.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The rewrite rules need to put put under the `<VirtualHost *:80>` before the https redirect. Why... not sure. But that's the only way it works.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName sub.example.com
  DocumentRoot /var/www/html/sub
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?url=$1 [L]
  RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto} !https
  RewriteRule . https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R]
</VirtualHost>
```

Answer (score -1):

Put your Redirect config there:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName blog.example.com
    Redirect / http://example.com/blog/
</VirtualHost>
```

Write this code on your .htaccess file.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^([^\.]+)\.example\.com$
RewriteRule ^/(.*)$ http://example.com/%1/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: 1) Not using an .htaccess file. Apache says: You should avoid using .htaccess files completely if you have access to httpd main server config file. Using .htaccess files slows down your Apache http server. Any directive that you can include in a .htaccess file is better set in a Directory block, as it will have the same effect with better performance. http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/howto/htaccess.html ... 2) doesn't solve the problem of mapping sub.example.com/some/path to sub.example.com?url=/some/path

Comment: Well, it also doesn't answer the question at all.